# Trouble with Coq type classes when defining recursive dependent fields

Tags: recursion, typeclass, coq

I am trying to define a set of descriptions and their interpretation into Coq Types, and this is what I came up with so far:

```
Class Desc (D : Type) :=
  { denotesInto : D -> Type
  ; denote : forall (d : D), denotesInto d
  }.

Notation "⟦ d ⟧" := (denote d).

Inductive TypeD : Type :=
| ArrowD : TypeD -> TypeD -> TypeD
| ListD  : TypeD -> TypeD
| NatD   : TypeD
.

Global Instance Desc_TypeD : Desc TypeD :=
  { denotesInto := fun _ => Type
  ; denote := fix go d :=
      match d with
      | ArrowD dL dR => (go dL) -> (go dR)
      | ListD  dT    => list (go dT)
      | NatD         => nat
      end
   }.
```

When declaring the `Desc_TypeD` instance, I initially wanted to define it as:

(need some text here so that SO will format the next code block :(...)

```
Global Instance Desc_TypeD : Desc TypeD :=
  { denotesInto := fun _ => Type
  ; denote :=
      match d with
      | ArrowD dL dR => ⟦ dL ⟧ -> ⟦ dR ⟧
      | ListD  dT    => list ⟦ dT ⟧
      | NatD         => nat
      end
   }.
```

But Coq would not let me. It seems to me that, it tries to resolve those calls to denote as some other instance that it can't find, while really they were meant to be a recursive call to the instance being defined.

Is there any convincing that will let me write this instance without the explicit `fix`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to know why the `fix` bothers you without knowing more about you context. One way to get something close to what you want is to open up your `TypeD`, however, this will surely have other downsides:

```
Class Desc (D : Type) :=
  { denote : forall (d : D), Type }.

Notation "⟦ d ⟧" := (denote d).

Inductive TypeD (D : Type) : Type :=
| ArrowD : D -> D -> TypeD D
| ListD  : D -> TypeD D
| NatD   : TypeD D
.

Global Instance Desc_TypeD D `{DI : Desc D} : Desc (TypeD D) :=
  { denote := fun d =>
      match d with
      | ArrowD _ dL dR => ⟦dL⟧ -> ⟦dR⟧
      | ListD _ dT     => list ⟦dT⟧
      | NatD _         => nat
      end
  }.
```

Note that we also need to make `denote`'s type more general as we cannot get enough information about the parameter `D`.

Comment: Ah, this is interesting! I will ask another question with another design trouble I'm having with this. Thanks!

Comment: This might depart too much from my descriptions though, as I cannot nest `ArrowD` for instance.

Comment: One of my problems with the explicit `fix` is that my proof contexts look like this: http://paste.awesom.eu/wERj

Comment: The proof context looks fine to me, next step you'd like to do is to destruct the types, right? [I would personally use the typical `nosimpl` tricks + views, etc... to structure the final proof, but that's just a detail]

Comment: Oh, what I mean is, I don't like that all those `fix`es are expanded. I found a solution though, by defining a fixpoint prior to defining the instance, and just referring to it in the instance.

Comment: Will Coq let you take the fixpoint of that `TypeD` functor? Answering my one question: yes it will! `Inductive Type' : Type := Fix : TypeD Type' -> Type'.`. I'm surprised tbh.